# CGO: how to free memory allocated in C using malloc from go to avoid memory leak

Tags: memory-management, go, memory-leaks, malloc, cgo

I am trying to use CGO to call an optimized C++ CPU-bound implementation of a complex algorithms from golang. Basically, it will pass a string into c++ function and get a string back. A simplified version of the code can be seen in the below:

#### algo.go

```go
package main

//#cgo LDFLAGS:
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//char* echo(char* s);
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    cs := C.CString("Hello from stdio\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    var echoOut *C.char = C.echo(cs)
    //defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(echoOut)); -> using this will crash the code
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(echoOut));
}
```

#### algo.cpp

```c++
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    char* echo(char* o) {
        int len = sizeof(o) / sizeof(char);
        char* out = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(out, o);
        return out;
    }
}
```

In this link, ppl mentions that C++ code should call "free" by itself to free the allocated memory: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/149hxezftf/go-nuts-cgo-is-it-safe-to-malloc-and-free-in-seperate-c-functions. But then it's very tricky because my c++ function return an allocated pointer so that golang can get the result. I cannot call free in the c++ code? What should be the correct way to handle this? I have a webserver will call the c++ code per each request and want to make sure it doesn't introduce any memory leak.

Thanks.

Comment: You say calling `C.free` crashes the code. What's the error? What's the stack trace look like? Calling `C.free` in Go is exactly like calling it in C. You have to know who is responsible for freeing the memory, and when it's safe to.

Comment: Hi thanks. my code crashed because i allocated memory in c++ wrongly. But I just notice even after fixing the allocated memory bug, my code are still suffering from memory leak issue. It seems that i would have to free memory within c++ code or pass go pointer to c++ pointer instead (avoid using malloc) What would be the correct way to pass back string from c++ code to gocode?

Comment: Seems that the memory leak was because of other parts of my code. Thanks.

Comment: @auxdx I am facing the same issues. A memory leak. once passed from c++ to go freeing just doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the memory allocation bug in your `echo` function. For example,

`algo.go`:

```go
//algo.go
package main

//#cgo LDFLAGS:
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//char* echo(char* s);
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    cs := C.CString("Hello from stdio\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    var echoOut *C.char = C.echo(cs)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(echoOut))
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(echoOut))
}
```

`algo.cpp`:

```c++
//algo.cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    char* echo(char* o) {
        char* out = (char*)malloc(strlen(o)+1);
        strcpy(out, o);
        return out;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ cd algo
$ go build && ./algo
Hello from stdio

$
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I am still wondering if i should release the memory in go using  defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(echoOut)) or it has to be somewhere within c++ code ?

Comment: Btw, I just realized that my code is leaking memory. Seems that i would have to free c++ malloc'ed memory or pass go pointer to c++ code instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following go version `go version go1.8 linux/amd64` and I have no problems running your code after uncommenting your deferred C.free.

I added a loop to allow me to track memory leaks via htop. Without the deferred free it does leak, but uncommenting it fixes the problem.

The code is below.

```go
//algo.go
package main

//#cgo LDFLAGS:
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//char* echo(char* s);
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000000000; i++ {
        allocateAndDeallocate()
    }
}

func allocateAndDeallocate() {
    cs := C.CString("Hello from stdio\n")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    var echoOut *C.char = C.echo(cs)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(echoOut)) // no crash here
}
```

---

```c++
//algo.cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {

    char* echo(char* o) {
        int len = sizeof(o) / sizeof(char);
        char* out = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(out, o);
        return out;
    }

}
```